# React index.html wrong path after npm run build

Tags: reactjs, npm

Hi peopole i have a problem with my index.html file builded by react npm run build. 
In the index.html file i have href="/manifest.json"> like this and i want like this href="manifest.json">
I try in package.json to put homepage like this  "homepage": "" but doesn't work

Comment: Why you are trying to remove the / from manifest.json ?

Comment: because i load the content of the build folder in a subfolder of a site. With the / doesn't work. Without yes

Comment: If you know the context path of the site you can set homepage of package.json according to that path. For example; /rootContextPath/subfolder/manifest.json

Comment: probably it works but this is a multisite component, so any time i build it i must change the homepage correctly for every site.